# custom dialog java swing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I am trying to write an custom SwingUtilities.InvokeandWait event , containing Textarea and Button ,so the once the user paste the data into Textarea and click button . Till then control should not go down ,but couldn't make it work correctly.

I figured out the best way would be using an dialog message, so now I am trying add a bigger TextArea instead of single line textfield in the InputDialogBox. 
I also tried to create a custome Dialog box but the InvokeandWait even just triggers the dialog box and goes to next lines  which I don't want.

I need help from experts

1. way to add a Textarea instead of single line textfield in inputdialog
   (or)
2. way to handle the custom dialog till I press ok button in it and then control goes to next line of the program.

Answer (score 3):

One simple example to create a Custom Dialog -

```
public class CustomDiaglogBox extends JFrame
{
    // Variables declaration
    private JLabel jLabel_Item;
    private JLabel jLabel_Value;
    public static JButton jButton_Add;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static JComboBox combo_item;
    public static JComboBox combo_value;
    public static JTextField text_Value;        
    public static JTextArea textArea_desc;      
    // End of variables declaration    

    public CustomDiaglogBox()
    {
        super();
        create();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }    

    private void create()
    {
        jLabel_Item = new JLabel();
        jLabel_Value = new JLabel();
        jLabel_Description = new JLabel();
        combo_value = new JComboBox();
        text_Value = new JTextField();          
        textArea_desc = new JTextArea(20,20);
        combo_item = new JComboBox(new String[]{""});
        combo_item.setSelectedIndex(-1);    
        jButton_Add = new JButton();
        contentPane = (JPanel)this.getContentPane();    
        //
        // jLabel1
        //
        jLabel_Item.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        //jLabel_Item.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
        jLabel_Item.setText("Item");
        //
        // jLabel2
        //
        jLabel_Value.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    //  jLabel_Value.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
        jLabel_Value.setText("Value");

        // jButton1
        //
        jButton_Add.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
        jButton_Add.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
        jButton_Add.setText("Add");
        jButton_Add.setEnabled(false);
        jButton_Add.addActionListener(new AddTagWidnowListener());      //
        // contentPane
        //
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addComponent(contentPane, jLabel_Item, 5,10,106,18);
        addComponent(contentPane, jLabel_Value, 5,47,97,18);
        addComponent(contentPane, new JLabel("Description"), 5,87,97,18);
        addComponent(contentPane, combo_item, 110,10,183,22);
        addComponent(contentPane, combo_value, 110,45,183,22);
        addComponent(contentPane, new JScrollPane(textArea_desc), 110,75,183,62);
        addComponent(contentPane, jButton_Add, 150,145,83,28);          
        this.setTitle("MY CUSTOM DIALOG");
        this.setLocation(new Point(276, 182));
        this.setSize(new Dimension(335, 221));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A JDialog is just like a JFrame. You can add any component to it that your want.

Also, you don't use invokeAndWait(). Just make the dialog modal and it will work the way you want.